# Auto Complete JCombobox

Tags: java, jcombobox

How to have *auto complete JCombobox* so, that it should suggest an item which have typed word or phrase in it **anywhere in the string** not just starting with that string.
I'm  using **eclipse juno IDE** and solution should be **JDK 1.5 supported**

Comment: How can you expect someone to help when you do not show what all you've tried? we can help, but cannot do work for you

Comment: [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm) i tried this one but, it only suggest item that start with typed string

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own KeySelectionManager which will be invoked when any key is typed. Default behavior is to select entry that starts with given character but you can modify it to get the current text from the text field component in the jcombo box and then select the matching entry.

You will need to look at following method in detail:

```
javax.swing.JComboBox.setKeySelectionManager(KeySelectionManager)
```